# GDocs embedded not shown in safari

Tags: pdf, mobile-safari, google-docs

I'm using gDocs viewer in order to embedded a pdf document: [example](http://www.clasesdeapoyo.com/archivo?file=http://clasesdeapoyonuevo.s3.amazonaws.com/selectividad/enunciados/m2em9.pdf&name=Examen%20de%20selectividad%3a%202013%20-%20Modelo). I use the following code to achieve this:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://clasesdeapoyonuevo.s3.amazonaws.com/selectividad/enunciados/m2em9.pdf&amp;embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:600px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It shows fine in normal browsers but when I tried to access via safari for iOS the iframe shows a blank space and not load.

What is it happening? What can I do in order to solve this? Is there another easy solution to embed a pdf document? I read about pdf.js but I want a easier solution.

Thanks